# How to 'join' two indexes in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have two indexes that must be separated:

```
// index = `order_item`
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Shoes",
    "Price": 9.99,
    "OrderID": 82
},{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Hat",
    "Price": 19.99,
    "OrderID": 82
}

// index = `order`
{
    "ID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith"
}
```

How would I 'join' these two tables on a search, such that it would return something along the lines of:

```
results = {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Shoes",
    "Price": 9.99,
    "Order.ID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith"
},{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Hat",
    "Price": 19.99,
    "Order.ID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it can't be done David

Comment: @eliasah -- I see, thank you. What would be your suggestion here then as how we might be able to merge the data. For example, something like a processing job that merges it and then creates a third index. Are there any possibilities here?

Comment: Have you considered a parent/child relationship between the documents? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html note that individual indexes aren't tables like in a RDBMS.

Comment: It depends on the size of the data of course. A processing job to perform joins would be suitable in this case to create a third index like you suggest sound like a perfect idea. I usually use Elasticsearch on top of Spark to perform transformations on big data.

Comment: @eliasah interesting. Are you available for consulting work regarding es + Spark? If so do you have a link or some way I could connect. Thanks.

Comment: You can find some resources on the Elasticsearch official website concerning Elasticseach Hadoop. And I have also answered a question were I post parts of code on that topic

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone. It's not easy to navigate on the site here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/32667068/3415409

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join query in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As answered in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288503/elasticsearch-map-two-sql-tables-with-a-foreign-key), nothing prevents you from storing the `Customer` name inside each `order_item` document at indexing time, while still having a dedicated index `orders` also containing the `Customer` data. Remember that it's all about cleverly denormalizing your data so that each of your documents be as "self-contained" as you need.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/order_items/order_item/1 -d '{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Shoes",
    "Price": 9.99,
    "OrderID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith"
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/order_items/order_item/2 -d '{
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Hat",
    "Price": 19.99,
    "OrderID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith"
}
```

The advantages of this solution is that each order item is completely self-contained, and you can group/aggregate them on `OrderID` in order to get all items of a given order.

Also, as @JohnAment mentioned in his comment, the `order/order_item` use case is also a good candidate for using either

1. the [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html)
2. or [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html).

In the first case, you'd have one `order` "parent" document...

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/orders/order/82 -d '{
    "ID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith"
}'
```

And several `order_item` "children" documents that you index using their parent ID:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/order_items/order_item/1?parent=82 -d '{
     "ID": 1,
     "Name": "Shoes",
     "Price": 9.99
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/order_items/order_item/2?parent=82 -d '{
     "ID": 2,
     "Name": "Hat",
     "Price": 19.99
}'
```

In the second case, your `order` document would contain all order items in a nested `OrderItems` property and would look like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/orders/order/82 -d '{
    "ID": 82,
    "Customer": "John Smith",
    "OrderItems": [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Shoes",
        "Price": 9.99
      },{
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Hat",
        "Price": 19.99
      }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: do you have any new updates to this approach, especially since mapping multiple types is being affected in elastic 6 ?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni parent/child is still possible in ES6 via `join` fields, although you can now only have a single parent/child join per index.

Comment: ok and would you prefer nested objects or join fields when you have lot of filtering and sorting needs just like what SQL where clause and order by does

Comment: @KalpeshSoni It really depends on the use cases. Feel free to create a new question highlighting your specific needs.

Comment: there is a typo. Use comma (,) after 
 "Customer": "John Smith"

Comment: for "localhost:9200/order_items/order_item/1?parent=82" elastic response with "request [/order_items/order_item/1] contains unrecognized parameter: [parent]"  @Val

Comment: @mohammadtwin feel free to create a new question describing your issue

Comment: @Val asked here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098816/parent-child-relationship-didnt-work-in-elasticsearch"