# How to write Elasticsearch Query Builder Join query in Java using two indexes where each index has one common field(column)?

Tags: java, join, elasticsearch

I have two indexes my first index test file is as follow:

```
{
"took": 31,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 1,
  "successful": 1,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 259636,
  "max_score": 0.012848643,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "testtype",
        "_id": "AV0TAUuCWj5Ta51I8M6S",
        "_score": 0.012848643,
        "_source": {
           "resource": "a6fa3184-3845-475e-b87b-866a92edae0c",
           "cookie_user": "9e3f8294-b0b8-89b2-55c6-94ec49bb2322",
           "user": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"

        }
     }
    }
```

My second index resources file is as follow

```
    {
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
    },
  "hits": {
  "total": 84796,
  "max_score": 1,
         "hits": [
           {
          "_index": "resources",
        "_type": "resourcestype",
        "_id": "AV0SrP_Sa_bOoMdWCF42",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "haseditor": [
              "equipo didactalia"
           ],
           "hasnumeroComentarios": [
              "0"
            ],

           "ID": "a6fa3184-3845-475e-b87b-866a92edae0c",

           "hasTituloDesc": [
              " is there a relationship between tempo and genre  "
           ],
           "haspublicador": [
              "consultor2 gnoss"
           ]
        }
     } 
    }
```

The resource field of test index document is same as ID field of resources index document.

I want to write a query to find all fields of both index documents having resource value "a6fa3184-3845-475e-b87b-866a92edae0c" of test document equal to ID value of resources document.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335303/how-to-join-two-indexes-in-elasticsearch/33338598#33338598

Comment: Thanks @Val for your comment but I need Java querybuilder query

Comment: What the answer suggests is that you should take some time to think about how to properly denormalize your data beforehand in order to get rid of the necessity of doing a JOIN.