# How to join two sources in two index's for elastic search

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have two index's with one common source. PFB those indexes.

**Index1-Products/**

```
Product I'd : 101
Product name: Laptop
Price : 100$

Product I'd : 102
Product name: Television
Price : 50$

Product I'd : 103
Product name: Washing machine
Price : 75$
```

**Index2- Dealers**

```
Dealer I'd : 3001
Dealer name: David
Product I'd: 103

Dealer I'd : 3002
Dealer name: Warner
Product I'd: 101
```

Now I want to join those two indexes with Product I'd as primary and get the results of those dealers details with Product name using CURL command.

Can anyone suggest the way to fetch the Details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'join' two indexes in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335303/how-to-join-two-indexes-in-elasticsearch)