# Master Data Mapping in ES Result

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way in ES to map master data with search result.

Example:-

- I have Employee and EmployeeType tables in RDBMS
- EmployeeType has 2 fields - Id and EmployeeTypeName(Admin, Management, Job Level 1)
- In Employee table I have mapped EmployeeTypeId (Foreign Key)

When I retrieve Employee Data I want to get EmployeeTypeName along with Id.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288503/elasticsearch-map-two-sql-tables-with-a-foreign-key/33294753#33294753 (hint: denormalize)

Comment: This approach would be difficult in my use case, I have Multilingual as well - Ill end up in storing multiple values and incase of update it would complicate. Any other way?

Comment: You can try either [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), but updating is not easy either, or [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html).